# How do I rename the currently running executable to another name?

Tags: c++, windows

im a beginner with cpp, and wanted to ask you how to check on application start if the name is "test.exe", if it already is it will just print "yes, this is right", if it's not it will rename it to test.exe

Tried searching for it online, and i could only find a function to rename it ONLY specifying the file name.
Es:

```
int value;
 
value = rename("fake.exe", "test.exe");
```

But if people renamed it to something different than `fake.exe` it obviously won't work.

EDIT after some answers: Guys, as i said the code works, but only if the name of the file (in this case) is fake.exe, which no one would rename it like that.

So i'm asking to get a part of code that changes the name of the app whatever the name is.

Comment: _"argv[0] is the pointer to the initial character of a null-terminated multibyte string that represents the name used to invoke the program itself (or an empty string "" if this is not supported by the execution environment)."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function It's not exactly what you asked. People can set a symlink to your application and call it through the symlink. In that case the name of the symlink will be passed as first parameter.

Comment: You can’t rename it because it is a running process!

Comment: @AndrewTruckle as i said the function i use works, but the problem is that it only works if the name of the file is `fake.exe`

Comment: Some operating systems will not let you rename the executable for a running process.  Some operating system will not let you rename the executable unless your account has privileges to do that operation.

Comment: @ThomasSablik sorry but i don't see the point in your answer, nor i understand it

Comment: Your question title is completely misleading. Your question is not how to rename a file. You know how to rename a file. Your question is how to find the path and name of the executable. My first comment describes how you can get the path to the executable.

Comment: As i said @ThomasSablik im a beginner, so i thought this was the best possible title.

Comment: The link in my first comment describes how to get the path to your file. You can use that path to rename the file.

Comment: @tho Passing the executable name as the first command line argument is a *convention*, not a contract.

Comment: @IInspectable OP uses Windows. Do you know a Windows system with different behavior?

Comment: @tho That convention isn't controlled by the OS. Any program is at liberty to call [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) as it sees fit.

Comment: @IInspectable So you have an better idea?

Comment: @tho Like `GetModuleHandle` and `GetModuleFileName` (and friends)?

Comment: @IInspectable Probably you should write an answer. I don't have a Windows system and I'm not Windows developer.